# Error Laravel 9 Ruta No definida, Cuando si lo esta

Tags: laravel, routes

Tengo un formulario el cual el action lo estoy redirigiendo a una ruta en laravel 9, por mas que le asigno el nombre a la ruta o cambie los parametros sigue presentando el mismo error "Route [registrar_usuario] not defined."

El índice de mi formulario:

```
<form class="form-registro" method="post" id="registerUserForm" action="{{ route('registrar_usuario') }}">
```

Rutas:

```
Route::post('/registrar_usuario', [ControladorPrincipal::class, 'registroUsuario'])->name('registrar_usuario');

Route::post('/registrar_usuario', [ControladorPrincipal::class, 'registroUsuario']);

Route::post('registrar_usuario','ControladorPrincipal@registroUsuario')->name('registrar_usuario');
```

Con las distintas maneras en que estoy llamando la ruta del formulario nunca encuentra dicha ruta definida.

Comment: Lista las rutas `php artisan route:list` a ver si aparece. Si no, limpia la cache `php artisan optimize:clear` y vuelve a listar las rutas

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que estaba ocurriendo. necesitaba limpiar cache.

Comment: Genial, ese comando optimize:clear, limpia todas las caches, no sólo las rutas, puedes leer en la documentación acerca del cache de rutas [Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-caching). Típicamente en un entorno de desarrollo no se cachea nada, para poder trabajar más cómodo, y sí se usa cachear en entornos de producción.

Comment: Ahora si lo resolviste, te invito a que escribas una respuesta explicando cómo lo hiciste y un enlace de referencia a la documentación, así le puede servir a otros con el mismo problema